# Translation for "Wir freuen uns auf Sie!" - Is "We are looking forward to you" formal and friendly enough?

Tags: translation, email, greetings, german

I need to write an email which my company sends out automatically. The goal is to remind users to log in to our online platform. The tone should be formal but also friendly. In German the equivalent for which I am trying to find a translation is "**Wir freuen uns auf Sie!**"

Is it appropriate to conclude the email by using "**We are looking forward to you**"? Or this expression uncommon in this form?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because translation requests are specifically off-topic for this Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You 'look forward to' an event, not a person. You could say "We look forward to welcoming you [to our site]", or even "...to seeing you" (which of course is metaphorical, as though the user will be physically visiting the company).